# How to store two variables (x.y) from a loop?

Tags: matlab, psychtoolbox

I am generating two different coordinates `(x, y)` within a loop. In my code, I have just realised that it is saving the last variable from the loop. I am, however, trying to save all the iterations from the `setsize` variable. I already tried to save using something like:

```matlab
circleposition = [0:length(setsize) x(i),y(i)];
```

But, it seems that I am not doing it correctly, getting the following error:

```
Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals.- 
Error using vertcat
Dimensions of matrices being concatenated are not consistent.
```

Here is my original code:

```matlab
setsize = 9; 
r = 340;
cx = 500;
cy = 500;
anglesegment = 2 * pi/setsize;
circleposition = []; 

for i = drange (0:setsize)
    x = r * cos(i*anglesegment) + cx;
    y = r * sin(i*anglesegment) + cy;
    circleposition = [x,y];
end
```

Output:

```matlab
circleposition =
             0    1.0000
      840.0000  500.0000
```

It runs only with the first/last iteration. I need to get 9 `x`'s and 9 `y`'s (depending the setsize, variable).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's kind of hard to follow, which error message comes from which attempt, but let's have a look.

I don't have access to the *Parallel Computing Toolbox*, which seems necessary to use the [for-loop over distributed range `drange`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/parallel-computing/for.html), but I assume, this loop can be replaced by `for i = 0:setsize` for testing.

Now, when starting at `i = 0`, you would try to access `x(0)` and `y(0)`, which is not allowed (*Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals*). Also, you would get 10 values instead of 9, as you stated in your question. So, let's start at `i = 1`.

To store all 9 pairs of `x` and `y`, your `circleposition` should be an `9 x 2` array So, initialize that by, for example, `circleposition = zeros(setsize, 2)`.

Last, you need to use proper indexing to store `[x, y]` at the `i`-th row of `circleposition`, i.e. `circleposition(i, :)`.

So, the corrected code (attention on the replaced `drange` part) could look like this:

```matlab
setsize = 9; 
r = 340;
cx = 500;
cy = 500;
anglesegment = 2 * pi/setsize;
circleposition = zeros(setsize, 2);     % Initialize circleposition appropriately

for i = 1:setsize                       % Start at i = 1
    x = r * cos(i*anglesegment) + cx;
    y = r * sin(i*anglesegment) + cy;
    circleposition(i, :) = [x, y];      % Correct indexing of the row
end 

circleposition                          % Output
```

The output would then be:

```matlab
circleposition =
   760.46   718.55
   559.04   834.83
   330.00   794.45
   180.50   616.29
   180.50   383.71
   330.00   205.55
   559.04   165.17
   760.46   281.45
   840.00   500.00
```

On the second error (*Error using `vertcat`. Dimensions of matrices being concatenated are not consistent.*): I don't see, where you used vertical concatenation at all!?

Answer (score 1):

Hear is code that works:

```
setsize = 9; 
r = 340;
cx = 500;
cy = 500;
anglesegment = 2 * pi/setsize;
circleposition = zeros(setsize + 1, 2); % Changed from circleposition = []

for i = drange (0:setsize)
    x = r * cos(i*anglesegment) + cx;
    y = r * sin(i*anglesegment) + cy;
    circleposition((i+1),:) = [x,y]; % Changed from circleposition = [x,y];
end
```

**Explanation:**

The fix was Changing `circleposition = [x,y];` to `circleposition((i+1),:) = [x,y]`. Without `((i+1),:)`, you are changing the data of `circleposition`, not adding to it.

Changing `circleposition = [];` to `circleposition = zeros(setsize + 1, 2);` was not required, its just recommended to allocate memory for speed, not an issue for small number of elements.

Comment: It'd be good to also explain why the OP code didn't work (what was wrong with it).